# Entity Framework Core MigrationBuilder "ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction."

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I am new to Entity Framework Migrations and using Migration Builder in `Entity Framework Core 2.2.4`  to create raw `Sql` statements but getting this exception

> ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction

Here is my code

```
public partial class EnableChangeTracking : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(@"IF(SELECT database_id FROM sys.change_tracking_databases WHERE database_id = DB_ID('xxx')) IS NULL
                               BEGIN
                                    ALTER Database [xxx]
                                    SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON(CHANGE_RETENTION = 7 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)
                               END
                               IF(SELECT [object_id] FROM sys.change_tracking_tables WHERE [object_id]=OBJECT_ID('xxx')) IS NULL
                                AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'xxx')
                               BEGIN
                                    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[xxx] ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING
                               END");
    }
}
```

Could anyone suggest how to fix this issue?

Comment: Well, since `ALTER DATABASE` should be the only statement in a command, you should **select** the `if` part ot your code, create conditional block, and run the `ALTER` in there.

Comment: @AgentFire. sorry i couldn't fully understand. do i need to seperate each sql statement in its own migration builder.sql call. if possible could you provide suggestion with code in the answer. thanks

Comment: Yes, separate the mentioned statement into a separate call against the DB.

Answer (score 3):

You should put each command in a separate .Sql statement inside your migration code.

Also, you should ensure to suppress transaction for each statement, like:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("ALTER DATABASE ListManagement SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON", true);
```

Sql method signature is outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.sql?view=efcore-2.1).

```
suppressTransaction - Boolean
```

Indicates whether or not transactions will be suppressed while executing the SQL.